# How to negate quantified expressions not using DeMorgan's law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am looking to write an expression from English to a logical expression, then negating that expression.

Give the expression

```
Some drivers do not obey the speed limit
```

Let

```
s(x) = x obeys the speed limit
```

Let the domain be drivers.

We can express the expression as such

```
∃x¬S(x)
```

Then we want to negate the expression.

The way I approached it is

```
-∃x¬S(x)
```

But in [this document](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2101-12/a1-sol.pdf) (#3 (a)) it states that the solution is

```
∀xS(x)
```

which is making me scratch my head.

The document states

```
¬∃x¬S(x) ≡ ∀xS(x)
```

but what law is this? This does not follow DeMorgan's law as that one states

```
￢∃xQ(x) ≡ ∀x ￢Q(x)
```

Am I missing something? How do we reach  ¬∃x¬S(x) ≡ ∀xS(x)? What law is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\neg \exists x \ \neg S(x) \overset{Quantifier \ DeMorgan}{=} \forall x \ \neg \neg S(x) \overset{Double \ Negation}{=} \forall x \ S(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

In your last DeMorgan's law quote, let $Q(x)=\lnot S(s).$ then apply the double negation law.

Answer (score 0):

deMorgan's Laws states duality between conjunction and disjunction under negation: $\neg(\phi(\alpha)\land\phi(\beta))=\neg\phi(\alpha)\lor\neg \phi(\beta)$ and $\neg(\phi\lor\psi)=\neg\phi(\alpha)\land\neg \phi(\beta)$ .

The universal quantifier is essentually a conjunction over the domain: it is a statement that the predicate function is true for *each* from the many entities in the domain. This and that and every other.

The existential quantifier is essentually a disjunction over the domain: it is a statement that the predicate function is true for *at least one* from many the entities in the domain. This or that or some other.

Then by mathematical induction, deMorgan's Laws are extended to these quantifiers.   $\neg\forall x~\phi(x) = \exists x~\neg\phi(x)$ and $\neg\exists x~\phi(x)=\forall x~\neg\phi(x)$